# Can't do a kubectl get on the TokenReview kind

Tags: kubernetes

I'm searching for out of date apis in my k8s cluster but when I try to do `kubectl get TokenReview --all-namespaces` , it comes back with `Error from server (MethodNotAllowed): the server does not allow this method on the requested resource`

I was expecting a list of different yaml files of the kind "TokenReview"  similar to the below
[image]

I'm running k8s 1.21 for server amd c.lient

anybody got any ideas?...not seeing anything in k8s docs

Answer (score 0):

Apparently,.... "TokenReview create requests are not persisted, they are answered with ephemeral responses. This means the token review API does not support read requests (get, list, watch, etc) or update/delete/patch requests, only create."

"All of the _Review resources are like this as well, subjectaccessreview, selfsubjectaccessreview, tokenreview, etc, are all non-persisted resources."

I raised this on github and this is what they said